# How to move Sticky Notes from taskbar to tray on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, sticky-notes

Sticky Notes seems very useful and I want to use it for my day to day tasks.

But when I open Sticky Notes, it always sits in the taskbar. If I could move it to the System Tray, then that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Sticky Notes Taskbar Hider](http://drakendev.com/sticky-notes-taskbar-hider.htm)  . It worked out for me on windows 8.1

From the website:

> Sticky Notes Taskbar Hider allows you to easily from hotkeys, or via the system tray icon, show or hide the Sticky Notes item from the taskbar. Other hotkeys allow you to launch Sticky Notes and also bring Sticky Notes to focus

Comment: Warning: Windows Defender flagged it malicious when I downloaded it. Might be false positive, but keep that in mind.

Comment: @Jan.J: I'm using it for 2 years now and I did not get any warning. I'm on Windows 10 with latest Defender definitions.

Comment: it doesnt work fo me on win 10

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible directly.

But there are some suggestions on this website:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/sticky-notes-stays-on-taskbar-instead-of-system/912d04d9-cbf5-4f13-9d73-2cecd1af20fb

Comment: Link-only answers tend to get stale quickly. Instead, briefly describe the contents of what you're linking to, making your answer much more useful and guarding against the page being moved.

Comment: Link is dead and/or requires authentication.